# Where can I save or share data between CircleCI builds?

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I'm trying to create a CircleCI job in which after a specific step, I want to save the output of that step somewhere that other jobs/builds can read it

The pseudo flow would look something like:

- A git branch triggers a build that has multiple jobs
- The output of one of the steps gets uploaded somewhere in circle (maybe artifacts?)
- Build completes

Then:

- A different branch runs a build
- When it gets to a job, it reads data that was uploaded by the previous build

Is there a good place to start for reading how to do this? I've been looking in circle's docs, but started getting a bit confused. Happy to answer any clarifying questions

Comment: What are the the outputs you want to have access to in other builds. The right solution probably depends on the nature of the artifacts. For example, if they are docker images or software packages, you want to upload them to an appropriate private repository.

Comment: @NickBailey the output would just be a string in this case